# How to insert data to my DB when using another model's field in my form?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two different models: Trainer and User. I'm pulling in the trainer_price field from Trainer into my form in User. Please note that I'm also not using a foreign key.

The problem I'm having is that the trainer_price is not getting inserted and the default value of 0 is there, which is not what I want.

The way the User form works is they fill out their name, address, email and the trainer_price is automatically populated once they selected a trainer. It's also a read-only field.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**user views.py**

```
def buyer(request):
    user_form = UserForm()
    trainer_listing = Trainer.objects.get(id=15).trainer_price

    context = {'user_form':user_form, 'trainer_listing':trainer_listing}

    if request.method == "POST":
      user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
      if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        return redirect("/success_page")

    return render(request, "user/user_form.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    Fullname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'John Doe'}))
    Email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    Mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '312-222-2222'}))
    Address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '1234 Main St'}))
    City = forms.CharField()
    State = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATES)
    zipcode = forms.CharField()
    trainer_price = forms.DecimalField(label="Trainer Price", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))

    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['Fullname','Email', 'Mobile', 'Address', 'City', 
                    'State', 'zipcode', 'trainer_price']
```

Any help in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we can set default values for the form field using the `initial` argument.

```py
def buyer(request):
    trainer = Trainer.objects.get(id=15)
    user_form = UserForm(initial={"trainer_price": trainer.trainer_price})
    # etc
```

PS. Make sure that you do not populate the value from the trainer_price with the results from the `request.POST`. Smart users could use this to get very cheap deals. In stead, always re-query the actual value.

Comment: Hi @Shine, thank you for your solution. I'm still not getting the trainer_price value inserted into the db for some reason. What would my context and html template look like?

Comment: Here's my context from my buyer view: `context = {'user_form':user_form, 'trainer':trainer.trainer_price}`

Comment: Check wether the trainer_price exists in the request.POST. If not it is very likely that if you're still doing it in a separate context value (`{'user_form':user_form, 'trainer_listing':trainer_listing}`) it is not passed correctly from the page. E.g. I would expect only the `user_form` in your context.